# Mustache/handlebars templating: figure out context data structure from template html

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, mustache

In mustache/handlerbars or any templating system in js, 
are there any tools to gather all the variables that a template refers to?

for example, given input

templateHTML:

```
<div class="{{divclass}}">
  {#item}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <span>{{text}}</span>
  {{/item}}
</div>
```

would return

```
{ 
  divclass: "",
  item: { 
    title: "",
    text: ""
  }
}
```

when used like `MyTemplateTool.getTemplateData(templateHTML)`

I tried googling around and checking out handlebars docs but could not find anything suitable

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just `.`. See the related [docs on paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths). Example:

```
{{#srcs}}
  <script src="{{.}}"></script>
{{/srcs}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing here? I would need to know what variables are used inside a template, when i have the template in a string or in the dom

Comment: Why do you need to get the template context from a template? Shouldn't your code be already generating that context and passing it in?

Comment: It's a situation where i would need to generate a 'content-editor' for html templates that are user-made. I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but i was curious if someone knew a tool for this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same in mind and I thought it was worth while writing something so here you go:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MustacheSchemaBuilder
{
    static String javaIdentifierRegExp = "[a-zA-Z_$0-9]+";
    static String tab = "    ";
    static Format format = Format.java;

    enum Format {
        json,
        java,
        ;
    }

    enum TagType {
        variable("\\{\\{\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}"),
        escapedVariable("\\{\\{\\{\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}\\}"),
        sectionStart("\\{\\{#\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}"),
        invertedSectionStart("\\{\\{\\^\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}"),
        sectionEnd("\\{\\{/\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}"),
        //partial("\\{\\{>\\s*" + javaIdentifierRegExp + "\\s*\\}\\}"),
        // no support for set delimiters or partials
        ;

        Pattern pat; 
        private TagType(String aRegExp) {
            pat = Pattern.compile(aRegExp);
        }

        public Pattern getPattern() { return pat; };
    }

    class Tag{
        public TagType type;
        public String identifier;
        Tag(TagType aType, String aIdentifier) { type = aType; identifier = aIdentifier;}

        public String toString() { return type.name() + " : " + identifier; }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object aOther) {
            if(!(aOther instanceof Tag)) return false;
            Tag ot = (Tag) aOther;
            return ot.type.equals(this.type) && ot.identifier.equals(this.identifier);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {return identifier.hashCode();}
    }

    class Node {
        public Section parent;
        public Tag tag;
        Node(Section aParent, Tag aTag){parent = aParent; tag = aTag; if(parent != null) parent.children.put(tag, this);}

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {return tag.hashCode();}

        public int depth() {
            int depth = 0;
            Node currentNode = this;
            while(currentNode.parent != null) {
                depth++;
                currentNode = currentNode.parent;
            }
            return depth;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < this.depth(); i++) sb.append(tab);
            switch(format) {
            case java:
                sb.append("public Object ").append(tag.identifier).append(";\n");
                break;
            case json:
            default:
                sb.append(tag.identifier).append(": {},\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    class Section extends Node{
        public Map<Tag, Node> children = new LinkedHashMap();
        Section(Section aParent, Tag aTag) { super(aParent, aTag); };

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < this.depth(); i++) sb.append(tab);
            switch(format) {
            case java:
                sb.append("public Object ").append(tag.identifier).append(" = new Object() {\n");
                for(Node child : this.children.values()) sb.append(child);
                for(int i = 0; i < this.depth(); i++) sb.append(tab);
                sb.append("};\n");
                break;
            case json:
            default:
                sb.append(tag.identifier).append(": {\n");
                for(Node child : this.children.values()) sb.append(child);
                for(int i = 0; i < this.depth(); i++) sb.append(tab);
                sb.append("},\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    class MustacheSchemaBuildException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        MustacheSchemaBuildException(String aMessage) {super(aMessage);}
    }

    Section rootSection;

    public MustacheSchemaBuilder(String aContents) throws Exception
    {
        TreeMap<Integer, Tag> tagMap = new TreeMap();
        for(TagType type : TagType.values()) {
            populateMap(tagMap, type, aContents);
        }
        System.out.println(tagMap);

        rootSection = new Section(null, new Tag(TagType.sectionStart, "$root$"));
        Section currentSection = rootSection;

        for(Tag tag : tagMap.values()) {
            if(currentSection.tag.type == TagType.invertedSectionStart) {
                if(tag.type == TagType.sectionEnd) {
                    if(!tag.identifier.equals(currentSection.tag.identifier))
                        throw new MustacheSchemaBuildException("The end tag: " + tag.identifier + " doesn't match the expected start tag: " + currentSection.tag.identifier + "\n\n" + rootSection);
                    currentSection = currentSection.parent;
                }
                continue;
            }
            switch(tag.type)
            {
            case variable:
                if(!currentSection.children.containsKey(tag))
                    new Node(currentSection, tag);
                break;
            case sectionStart:
                Tag invertedSectionStartTag = new Tag(TagType.invertedSectionStart, tag.identifier);
                if(!(currentSection.children.containsKey(tag) || currentSection.children.containsKey(invertedSectionStartTag))) 
                    new Section(currentSection, tag);
                currentSection = (Section)currentSection.children.get(tag);
                break;
            case invertedSectionStart:
                Tag sectionStartTag = new Tag(TagType.sectionStart, tag.identifier);
                if(!(currentSection.children.containsKey(tag) || currentSection.children.containsKey(sectionStartTag)))
                    new Section(currentSection, tag);
                currentSection = (Section)currentSection.children.get(sectionStartTag);
                break;
            case sectionEnd:
                if(!tag.identifier.equals(currentSection.tag.identifier))
                    throw new MustacheSchemaBuildException("The end tag: " + tag.identifier + " doesn't match the expected start tag: " + currentSection.tag.identifier + "\n\n" + rootSection);
                currentSection = currentSection.parent;
                break;
            default:
            }
        }
    }

    public void build() {
        System.out.println(rootSection);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String contents;
        try {
            contents = readFile(args[0], Charset.defaultCharset());

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file!");
            throw e;
        }

        MustacheSchemaBuilder builder = new MustacheSchemaBuilder(contents);

        builder.build();
    }

    void populateMap(Map<Integer, Tag> map, TagType aType, String aContents) {
        Matcher m = aType.getPattern().matcher(aContents);
        while(m.find()) {
            int start = m.start() + 3;
            if(aType == TagType.variable) start = m.start() + 2;
            map.put(m.start(), new Tag(aType, aContents.substring(start, m.end() - 2).trim()));
        }
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
    {
      byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
      return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
}
```

Give the template file path at the command line - you need java 7 or higher to open the file, or you can just rewrite the readFile - method. You can produce a json or java 'schema' by changing the format at the top of the class. The 'schema' gets written to stdout, you can copy it from there and paste it into where you need it. Hope this helps. Ah! This doesn't support partials or set delimiters, but if you get round to writing support ping it to me as I might want it :)